# Material Angular table not sorting column which contains objects

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm building a web app using angular material and am trying to display a table with sorting. The sorting works on all but this column. This is the only column where the type of the variable isn't a string or a number.

I've already try'd change column def to office.name etc, but to no avail.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="office">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Office </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.office.name }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Component Code:

```
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  dataTableColumns: string[] = ['name', 'emailAddress', 'office', 'active'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Data>;
  data: Data[];
  offices: Office[];
  value: string;
  oldFilterValue: string;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(ContextMenuComponent) public basicMenu: ContextMenuComponent;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger)
  contextMenu: MatMenuTrigger;

  contextMenuPosition = { x: '0px', y: '0px' };

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private officeService: OfficeService,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    this.getOffices();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.updateTable();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.dataService.get().subscribe((res) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.data= res as any[];
      this.updateTable();
    });
  }

  updateTable(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    if (this.value) {
      this.applyFilter(this.value);
    }
  }

  getOffices(): void {
    this.officeService.getOffices().subscribe((res) => {
      this.offices = res;
    });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

Comment: by default the angular material worked on root level keys value and you trying to sort on nested value `row.office.name` that's why it not work. follow the document: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

Comment: Yes I guess that's why it wasn't working, I was looking for a solution to this

Comment: check this example of sorting on nested object key working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef8lwu hope this will help to get out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sortingDataAccessor` on your data source to sort the object in your table.

Assuming that your data source name is `dataSrouce`

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;


ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(yourData);
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch(property) {
        case 'office.name': return item.office.name;
        default: return item[property];
      }
    };
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
}
```

And in your HTML, change `matColumnDef="office"` to `matColumnDef="office.name"`

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="office.name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Office </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.office.name }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I tried to just copy and paste this into my ngOnInit() method, but didn't seem to make a difference, am I supposed to change the html or put it in a different method?

Comment: After `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;`

Comment: unfortunately the updated one doesn't work either :(

Comment: Try to change your HTML, you need to set `office.name` instead of `office`. I've updated my answer. Does it help?

Comment: Got it working but had to set it up in the getData method bit, bit unsual. Thanks for all the help, bit of code duplication but it still works :)

Comment: Don't suppose you'd know how to fix it not filtering by office name? :( if not no worries